# Getting a lot of conflicts when upgrading anaconda to latest version

Tags: python, anaconda

I ran the command `conda install anaconda=2020.11` but got a lot of package conflicts.

```
Package gettext conflicts for:
cairo -> libglib[version='>=2.66.4,<3.0a0'] -> gettext[version='>=0.19.8.1,<1.0a0']
libgdal -> poppler[version='>=0.89.0,<0.90.0a0'] -> gettext[version='>=0.19.8.1,<1.0a0']
libglib -> gettext[version='>=0.19.8.1,<1.0a0']

Package get_terminal_size conflicts for:
_anaconda_depends -> get_terminal_size
anaconda=2020.11 -> get_terminal_size==1.0.0=h38e98db_0

Package pyjwt conflicts for:
oauthlib -> pyjwt[version='>=1.0.0']
requests-oauthlib -> oauthlib[version='>=3.0.0'] -> pyjwt[version='>=1.0.0']

Package chart-studio conflicts for:
cufflinks-py -> python-cufflinks==0.17.3=py_0 -> chart-studio[version='>=1.0.0']
python-cufflinks -> chart-studio[version='>=1.0.0']

Package glob2 conflicts for:
_anaconda_depends -> conda-build -> glob2[version='>=0.6']
anaconda=2020.11 -> glob2==0.7=py_0
conda-build -> glob2[version='>=0.6']
_anaconda_depends -> glob2

Package pytest-runner conflicts for:
phik -> pytest-pylint[version='>=0.13.0'] -> pytest-runner
scrapy -> parsel[version='>=1.5'] -> pytest-runner
parsel -> pytest-runner

Package glib-tools conflicts for:
poppler -> glib -> glib-tools==2.66.4[build='hf2a7229_2|he2d232f_2|h885f38d_2']
cairo -> glib[version='>=2.58.3,<3.0a0'] -> glib-tools==2.66.4[build='hf2a7229_2|he2d232f_2|h885f38d_2']

Package libffi conflicts for:
cairo -> libglib[version='>=2.66.4,<3.0a0'] -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0']
gettext -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0']
libglib -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0|>=3.3,<3.4.0a0']

Package sortedcollections conflicts for:
anaconda=2020.11 -> sortedcollections==1.2.1=py_0
_anaconda_depends -> sortedcollections

Package dnspython conflicts for:
faker -> email_validator==1.0.2 -> dnspython[version='>=1.15.0']
email-validator -> dnspython[version='>=1.15.0']

Package apscheduler conflicts for:
python-telegram-bot -> apscheduler=3.6.3
telegram-send -> python-telegram-bot[version='>=12.1.1'] -> apscheduler=3.6.3
```

Does it mean I have to install anaconda v2020.11 using the installation file since the package conflicts cannot be resolved without risking my current set-up?

I am currently using anavonda 2020.07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the main reasons for package conflicting is anaconda has changed the package storing mechanism recently. 
you can see that by going to the anaconda install folder, the `.conda` folder contains all the environments you have built, except the `base` environment. But in the new release, all the environments store inside the `ananconda3/envs` folder, and `.conda` use to connect external environments.
It is good to reinstall the anaconda again.
because environments in the `.conda` folder does not get affected by installing anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

When you run only `conda install anaconda=2020.11` it will only try to install the anaconda but an anaconda is dependent on the other packages as well that are required to install/update.
If you just want to upgrade the anaconda then run the command `conda update anaconda`. This command will resolve all of the conflicting packages.

Answer (score -1):

Though i agree with @Ankush Chavan but  I will recommend using anaconda installer from its official site as the installer will automatically set everything up. There will be no conflicts.

Comment: This answer should really be a comment on the answer of @AnkushChavan